# Unserialize parameter

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-development

I'm developing a contract whose storage is very large.

I have exactly 23 fields in a struct, that is the value part of a mapping.
All the data must be included at once, but given the stack size limit, I can't have all of them declared in the function signature.

So I was thinking about "compressing" most of the parameters into a serialized string (JSON, maybe), but I really need this data to be stored as independent fields. Therefore, I'd need to unserialize this big chunk of data.

Another possibility is to consider everything a big byte array, with fixed size fields, and then split it up in a predefined order.

Is any of these possible?

Comment: Interesting. I did not realise there was a stack size limit that would prevent many parameters being passed - " Not having a stack size limit - no particular justification either way; note that limits are not strictly necessary in many cases as the combination of gas costs and a block-level gas limit will always act as a ceiling on the consumption of every resource." from https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale .

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't tried it, that definitely seems possible. Assuming each of your 23 values's can fit into 32 bytes, you can use a `bytes32[23]`.

```
contract MyContract{
    struct MyStruct {...}
    function MyContract(bytes32[23] input) {
        MyStruct(input[0],input[1],...}
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but this is basically reinventing the wheel :D. If I have to write a stdlib for every contract, I'm screwed.